# Descendent or self selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, self, descendant

I want to search for all elements with class `needle` in all elements returned by `jQuery('.haystack')` and have tried `jQuery('.haystack .needle')`, but this doesn't seem to pick up the case where an element has both classes.  Is there a selector that will do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [combining selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
jQuery('.haystack.needle, .haystack .needle');
```

This will select all `.haystack`s that are also `.needle`s and any `.needle` which is a descendant of a `.haystack`, which I think is exactly what you asked for :-)

Answer (score 1):

You do this with no space in there, like this:

```
jQuery('.haystack.needle')
```

The alternative is:

```
jQuery('.haystack').filter('.needle')
```

With the space it's looking for *children* of those `.haystack` elements with `.needle`, without the space, you're matching the *same* elements, but saying they must have both classes to match now.  This is also what [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) does, it further cuts down the matches set to those elements also matching the selector you pass into it.